# Interesting examples of classes of ordered fields between ordered fields and real closed fields

Tags: reference-request, field-theory

Let $O$ be the class of ordered fields, and let $R$ be the class of ordered real-closed fields. I am wondering if there are interesting examples of classes of ordered fields in between those two classes. For example, I know of the class of Euclidean fields, and also of ordered Pythagorean fields. I am wondering if there is any research on other such classes of fields.

Comment: Does "Non-Archimedean ordered field" fit your definition? If so, look out for non-archimedean analysis unless you're interested only on 'algebraic'-oriented research.